# Change Woocommerce single product templates order based on product tag

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I have two templates, one for Panorama & Multi-Panel photographs, the other for Normal ones.

I'm trying to code a conditional statement that checks the product tag in order to select the relevant template to be displayed.

1. Panorama photos have the product tag 'panorama' or 'multi-panel'.
2. If the 'panorama' or 'multi-panel' tag is true >> perform some remove_action and add_action functionality on the Panorama product page...

...otherwise do nothing to the Normal product page...

This is what I have been dappling with to no affect!!

```
function robhemphill_panorama_layout () {

    if ( has_tag( array( 'panorama', 'multi-panel'))) {     

        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 10 );

    } else {    

         // Do nothing

    }

}   

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'robhemphill_panorama_layout' );
```

Any thoughts or ideas would be great, can't find anything online!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are targeting Woocommerce **product tags** (but not WordPress tags) try this instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'robhemphill_panorama_layout', 1 );
function robhemphill_panorama_layout () {
    global $product;

    if ( has_term( array( 'panorama', 'multi-panel' ), 'product_tag', $product->get_id() ) ) {

        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 10 );

    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).*

Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks so much, I've been at it for ages!